# preg_match doesn't work

Tags: php, preg-match, design-patterns, matching

I was trying to extract table where class is snapshot-table2
It return empty blank page.

Wondering what's wrong?

```
$output = file_get_contents('http://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=ROK&ty=c&ta=1&p=d&b=1');

$ismatch= preg_match('|<table width="100%" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="snapshot-table2">(.*?)</table>|si', $output, $matchresult);


if($ismatch)
{
    echo '<pre>';
        print_r($matchresult);
        echo '</pre>';

    //$processpeg= $matchresult[0];
}

exit;
```

Comment: Have you checked to make sure that file_get_contents is returning what you expect? maybe the reason you are getting a blank page after your preg_match is because it is not getting the data in the first place.

Comment: Hi Sherwin, data is confirm there. echo $ouput;

Comment: ried it for you too just in case, I got the results fine. You really need to be careful with hitting some sites repeatedly in a short time for info. They can see this activity, and block it, very easily. If they were really mean they could even send you incorrect information instead, similar to the infamous 'hotlink switcharoo'.

For general information that doesn't change much, maybe update it once a day or so as not to overload them. However if you need the info up to date at all times, like stocks and stuff, you'll need to find someone to provide an API or something to allow that access.

Comment: @ineedhelp +1 For nick name lol

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure `allow_url_fopen` is enabled so you can use a URL as a parameter to `file_get_contents`. Test if it is:

```
echo 'allow_url_fopen = ' . ini_get('allow_url_fopen');
```

Comment: His code works fine, his IP has been banned by the page he is requesting.

Answer (score 0):

Cannot be reproduced. Code works. They've blocked your server or something.

You could try `ini_set("user_agent", ..)` however.

Comment: Yeah I'm guessing a IP or agent block, code works fine here. In the future "i need help" I suggest you store the contents of a third party site into a cache with a reasonable expiry so you're not hammering the server with every page load.

Comment: hi mario and scuzzy, thank you so much for your valuable advice. You guys are great.